# windows XP, windows explorer address bar does not resolve hostnames

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

This is puzzling me from a while, if I use windows explorer to access a remote network share by IP it works fine, however it does not work if I use hostname

eg.

```
\\IP_address\c$  - works

\\hostname\c$ - does not work
```

from a command line I can ping the short/long hostname without any problems, I do have the windows "web client" service running, any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your software firewall is probably blocking File and Print Sharing (or at least ONE, but clearly not all, of the ports it uses). Go into your firewall properties and check it. You can also turn it off temporarily to test if that does not work.

[image]

Here is more on the ports used:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119493

One more thing to check is in your Network connection's properties. Make sure it is set to default, or enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP.

[image]

Comment: Disabled the firewall, had these settings in place and still nothing. It does not even work for localhost, I can \\127.0.0.1\c$, but can't \\localhost\c$ ! I've did ipconfig /displaydns and flushdns and worked fine, this is a bit odd.

Comment: That is very strange, ESPECIALLY for localhost not to work. I would consider resetting my TCP/IP settings with "netsh int ip reset" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357

Comment: still the same even after TPC/IP setting reset